# Data-description, data-title and SEO

Tags: javascript, seo, google-index

The content on our web is by default in link attributes data-title and data-description, i.e:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/inteokejnu" data-largesrc="images/facebook.png"
data-title="InteOkej på Facebook" data-description="Här finner du vår Facebook-sida.">
    <img src="images/thumbs/facebook-thumb.png" title="InteOkej på Facebook" alt="img01">
</a>
```

When clicking an image the content is generated as h3 and p tags with javascript.

This works fine except for when it comes to SEO where it doesn't works at all. The only thing Google has indexed so far is the attribute 'alt' on the images (which at the moment only says img01, img02 etc). This of course is something we'll change, but the question is how to do with the rest?

Is it some way one can make Google index what's inside data-title and data-attribute or is there another way to solve this?

**The site:** [www.inteokej.se](http://www.inteokej.se)

Answer (score 0):

The alt should describe the image, so "InteOkej på Facebook" would be better than "img01" in this case. If the title+description isn't too long, just make this you alt tag.

An alternative is HTML5 microdata or maybe add this to a real H3 and P and hide them with CSS. You could then take these without using the data attributes (if you want to).

HTML5 microdata: http://diveintohtml5.info/extensibility.html
Schema.org: http://schema.org/